# Virtual pages accessed by a each Process in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need the sequence of pages each process access ex:-

```
Process 1 access its Virtual page 2  
then Process 2 access its Virtual page 10 
then Process 1 access its virtual page 7
and so on ..
#in Linux environment
```

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: It's not immediately apparent that this information would be captured, except in the case where the access results in a fault because the page is not yet physically present and needs to be loaded - which would probably be true for the _first_ access to each page, excluding mappings inherited from a fork().  Of course if you are running a simulator or possibly virtual machine, or perhaps if the process of interest is being debugged it's more practical to record.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any utilties will give exact output as mentioned in the question, but you can look up these links:

http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1
http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html

The command mentioned is:

```
 cat /proc/<pid>/maps
```

You'll need to read through both the links to make sense of it and maybe modify the output according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old questions, but I thought may be someone in the future might get into the same problem.

I know that you can write a tool for PIN, which is a dynamic binary instrumentation tool,  that can do this for you. They have hooks that you can run just before or after a memory instruction is executed. You can use these hooks to dump the address targeted by that instruction.